# Processing a list of 6 million items

Tags: list, performance, kotlin, collections, operators

I have a CSV file with 6+ Million records. I am reading the CSV file and collecting each row(List) in an Array List. The entire list needs to run through a grouping logic and then finally push each group to a message queue system.

This is my code:

```
var header: Map<String, Int> by Delegates.notNull()
val rows = csv.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
  lines
    .filter {
      validate(it)
    }
    .filterNotNull()
    .map { line ->
      convert(line)
    }
    .toList()
}
parse(rows, header)
  .forEach { 
    this.send(it)
  }

fun parse(rows: List<List<String>>, header: Map<String, Int>): List<Domain> {
return rows
  .asSequence()
  .map { row ->
    mapToColumn(row)
  }
  .mapNotNull { it.getOrNull() }
  .filter(this::someFilter)
  .groupBy { it['xyz'] }
  .map { groupedRow ->
    mapToDomain(groupedRow)
  }
  .mapNotNull { it.getOrNull() }
  .flatten()
  .toList()
}
```

With 4GB RAM & 1 Core server, this crashes(Eats up server memory, and my application restarts).

This works well for a smaller list(2 Million) records but for 6M it fails.

I need help here to make it performant, maybe a better way to handle the grouping logic so that it eats less memory or maybe using different types of variables?

Comment: You will probably have to rewrite this in a way that it does not keep the entire CSV file in the heap. How big is `List<Domain>`, in the end? Can you even afford to keep this in memory? Is 6 million the absolute maximum size?

Comment: @Rubydesic The final grouped object(`List<Domain>`) will more likely have 5+ million records for sure, there is some filtration logic that will eliminate few records but only a few will be eliminated. I need to maintain the full list is due to the grouping logic, is there any other way of grouping the records without maintaining such a huge object in the memory?

Answer (score 1):

You may trade off memory for performance. You may read CSV file several times, getting elements of one group per pass (hope you have enough memory to store all elements of the biggest group):

```kotlin
val delimiter = "|"
val groupColumnIndex = 42

//read CSV line by line to capture only groups
val groups = csv.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
    lines
        .mapNotNull { it.split(delimiter).getOrNull(groupColumnIndex) }
        .toSet()
}

groups.forEach { group ->
    //read CSV line by line once again for each group
    val domainObjectsOfGroup = csv.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
        lines
            .mapNotNull { it.split(delimiter) }
            .filter { it.getOrNull(groupColumnIndex) == group }
            .filter { /* other filtering logic */ }
            .map { /* mapping to domain object*/ }
            .toList()
    }

    //send to MQS
    send(domainObjectsOfGroup)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea of operating bigger-sized files, in my scenario, I can tradeoff speed with performance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea using sequences I think, to avoid creating too many intermediate lists - which is probably your bottleneck here if you're running out of RAM. But you're not using them consistently, you're creating lists and other collections in a few places and that's going to eat up memory.

Here's some stuff you can look at at least - I'd recommend you look into some kind of benchmarking so you can track how much of an improvement you're making, even if it's just logging how many items you've processed and how big the heap is every so often!

---

```
  lines
    ...
    .toList()
```

First up, when you read in the file, `useLines` passes them into the lambda as a sequence (`lines`) - but you call `toList()` at the end and create a list containing all 6 million lines of the file. But the first thing you do with that list (`rows`) is generate a sequence from it again! Try dropping the `toList()` and leave `rows` as a `Sequence`

---

```
rows
  ...
  .groupBy { it['xyz'] }
```

This grouping function produces a `Map` of `List`s, containing every item in the sequence. You've done some filtering before this point, so maybe you don't have 6 million left, but unless you've really trimmed your data set down you're going to have a large map of stuff here - all the remaining items, and depending on how many groups there end up being, maybe millions of lists too.

Depending on exactly what you're doing, you might be able to avoid doing too much stuff at once, leaving you with a huge pile of results taking up memory. Have a look at the [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/chunked.html) function - it produces a `Sequence` of `List`s, so you can work on the data in sections, and each list is produced when you start working on it, not all at once.

Working with smaller collections might relieve some memory pressure since the system has more chance to garbage collect. You might be able to do your grouping in sections, do your domain mapping or whatever, then store the end result / pass it to the `send` function. Or call `toSequence` on it, so your chunked `Sequence<List<Thing1>>` eventually becomes a `Sequence<Sequence<Thing2>>` and you can `flatten` it.

I hope you get the general idea, that one's a little trickier and it really depends on what you're doing. The idea is basically to keep it a sequence as much as possible, and for where you need to create collections, you're doing "small" ones and turning them into back into one sequence so you don't collect them all together in memory.

---

```
  .map { groupedRow ->
    mapToDomain(groupedRow)
  }
  .mapNotNull { it.getOrNull() }
```

You can combine these two into

```
mapNotNull { groupedRow -> mapToDomain(groupedRow).getOrNull() }
```

You can do the same with your chained `filter -> filterNotNull` calls in the reader, but there it's a `Sequence` so it doesn't really matter, it's just an extra step. When you're working with an `Iterable` though, each `map` call produces a whole new collection, so if you can do one instead of two, them's some savings! I don't know if this would be simplified to one call by the compiler under the hood, but it's worth doing yourself where you can anyway.

---

```
rows
  ...
  .flatten()
  .toList()
```

At the end, you're creating a list. Even if you can do the chunked sequence approach I mentioned, the final result is that you're collecting everything that's left into one collection. Is this still going to be big? Too big?

*(If it's not too big then ignore this, because often a `Sequence` is less efficient than an `Iterable` - you need to benchmark and make that call!)*

What you're actually doing with this result is calling `forEach` on it and then passing each item into your `send` function - so again, this could easily be a `Sequence` - you don't need that intermediary `List`, all you're doing is iterating over it and doing something with each item, one at a time, which is what sequences are good for.

That `toList` call might be redundant anyway, depending on what `flatten` is returning here. If it's already a list, calling that again might create a whole new one, I'm not sure if the compiler would skip that

---

That's a lot of stuff, and I can only give you things to look at, I can't really tell you exactly how to write it for whatever your circumstances are. Hope it gives you some pointers though!

**tl;dr** try to keep things as a sequence, watch out for calls where it gets converted into an iterable, and try to avoid repeated steps on those (since each one creates a new collection). If you have to create an iterable, see if you can `toSequence` it as soon as possible to avoid creating more, and look into chunking.

**Also** see if you can write stuff out to storage at any point. Streaming it to a file by having a nice straight sequence would be cool, but if you end up with a big-ass list, maybe writing it for later further processing is the right thing to do. Just something to think about!

ok that was long

Comment: You are right, I have unnecessary lists which is eating the memory, let me try to refactor my code based on your suggestions.